# How to center a responsive navigation dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css

i would like to center a responsive navigation drop-down menu, but i can't do it... 
This is my website : [utopia-market.com](http://utopia-market.com)

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: I set the `ul` to `width: 100%` and it worked. Also, I'd add a minimal version of your code the the question to prevent link decay.

Comment: Please provide relevant code samples here so we can understand your problem.

Comment: Please read this: [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and create a [mcve] in the question itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your ul is on absolute position, you just need to add a left and right properties to your menu like this:

```
#menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0; /* THERE */
  right: 0; /* AND THERE */
}
```

Comment: don't add code snippet if you have nothing to show in output. just simply use code for that.

Comment: thanks so much it works! but now when i'm resizing the window, there is a problem, there is double menu...?

Comment: Then you have to set your responsive menu with media-queries :)